# Clustering of wso2 APIM Analytics 2.0

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-api-manager

How is clustering done with latest wso2 APIM analytics 2.0 and how auto scaling is achieved for analytics with other components of APIM?

Answer (score 1):

Following is the clustering guide for APIM 2.0.0

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0

In order to cluster APIM analytics 2.0.0 you can follow the DAS clustering guide.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Minimum+High+Availability+Deployment+-+DAS+3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no clustering guide created for this. But you can refer [1] to create an analytics cluster and [2] to configure analytics on APIM side. An issue is raised to create required guides. You can follow [3] for the status of this.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Minimum+High+Availability+Deployment+-+DAS+3.0.1

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+APIM+Analytics

[3] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DOCUMENTATION-3620